# Ошибки при добавлении cpp файла

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь подключить другие cpp файлы. При добавлении выдает ошибки:

```
LNK2005 "__int64 __cdecl powmod(__int64,__int64,__int64)" (?powmod@@YA_J_J00@Z) уже определен   
LNK2005 "__int64 __cdecl powmod(__int64,__int64,__int64)" (?powmod@@$$FYA_J_J00@Z) уже определен в Pollard.obj  all_metods  
LNK1169 обнаружен многократно определенный символ - один или более  all_metods
```

Код файла Shenks.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "methods.h"
#include <map>

using namespace std;

__int64 powmod(__int64 a, __int64 b, __int64 m) {
    __int64 res = 1;
    while (b > 0)
        if (b & 1) {
            res = (res * a) % m;
            --b;
        }
        else {
            a = (a * a) % m;
            b >>= 1;
        }
        return res % m;
}

__int64 Shenks(__int64 a,__int64 b,__int64 m) {
    __int64 n = (__int64)sqrt(m) + 1;
//  __int64 *r;
//  r = new __int64[n];
    map<__int64,__int64> vals;
    for (__int64 i = n; i >= 1; --i)
        vals[powmod(a, i * n, m)] = i;
    for (__int64 i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
        __int64 cur = (powmod(a, i, m) * b) % m;
        if (vals.count(cur)) {
            __int64 ans = vals[cur] * n - i;
            if (ans < m)
                return ans;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Код файла Pollard.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "methods.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

__int64 powmod(__int64 a, __int64 b, __int64 m) {
    __int64 res = 1;

    while (b > 0)
        if (b & 1) {
            res = (res * a) % m;
            --b;
        }
        else {
            a = (a * a) % m;
            b >>= 1;
        }
        return res % m;
}

__int64 gcdex(__int64 a, __int64 b, __int64 &x, __int64 &y) {
    if (b == 0) {
        x = 1;
        y = 0;
        return a;
    }
    __int64 x1, y1;
    __int64 d1 = gcdex(b, a % b, x1, y1);
    x = y1;
    y = x1 - (a / b) * y1;
    return d1;
}

__int64 ReverseElement(__int64 a, __int64 N) {
    __int64 x, y, d;
    d = gcdex(a, N, x, y);
    if (d != 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return x;
}

__int64 NOD(__int64 a, __int64 b)
{
    while (a > 0 && b > 0)

        if (a > b)
            a %= b;

        else
            b %= a;

    return a + b;
}

__int64 phi(__int64 n) {
    __int64 result = n;
    for (__int64 i = 2; i*i <= n; ++i)
        if (n % i == 0) {
            while (n % i == 0)
                n /= i;
            result -= result / i;
        }
    if (n > 1)
        result -= result / n;
    return result;
}

__int64 Pollard(__int64 a, __int64 b, __int64 p)
{
    vector<__int64> z(214783640), u(214783640), v(214783640);
    z[0] = 1;
    __int64 ph = phi(p);
    __int64 ak = 0, ev = 0, eu = 0, nod, chk;
    __int64 p1 = p - 1;
    __int64 x = 0;
    for (__int64 i = 0; i < p; i++)
    {
        if (z[i] % 3 == 1)
        {
            z[i + 1] = b * z[i] % p;
            u[i + 1] = u[i] % ph;
            v[i + 1] = (v[i] + 1) % ph;
        }
        if (z[i] % 3 == 2)
        {
            z[i + 1] = z[i] * z[i] % p;
            u[i + 1] = 2 * u[i] % ph;
            v[i + 1] = 2 * v[i] % ph;
        }
        if (z[i] % 3 == 0)
        {
            z[i + 1] = a * z[i] % p;
            u[i + 1] = (u[i] + 1) % ph;
            v[i + 1] = v[i] % ph;
        }
        if (*find(z.begin(), z.begin() + i, z[i + 1]) != *(z.begin() + i))
        {
            ak = distance(z.begin(), find(z.begin(), z.begin() + i, z[i + 1]));
            ev = v[ak] - v[i + 1];
            if (ev < 0)
                ev += p1;
            eu = u[i + 1] - u[ak];
            if (eu < 0)
                eu += p1;
            nod = NOD(ev, p1);
            ev /= nod;
            eu /= nod;
            p1 /= nod;
            chk = ReverseElement(ev, p1);
            if (chk < 0)
                chk += p1;
            x = chk*eu%p1;
            if (powmod(a, x, p) != b)
                x += p1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

Как я понял, потому что используется одинаковая функция powmod. Как правильно исправить?

Comment: Вы не уточняете, куда именно Вы пытаетесь добавить cpp файлы. Похоже, нужно в систему сборки добить cpp файл

Comment: Хе хе хе... "бНОПНЯ ВХРЮК?"

Comment: да, и причина в том, что кто то забыл в header файле добавить гуарды (ifdef или pragma once) либо просто накопипастил одно и то же.

Comment: @KoVadim А как тут могли/могут помочь гуарды?

Comment: если их правильно расставить...

Comment: @KoVadim В вопросе пока что вообще никаким боком не фигурирровали заголовочные файлы.

Comment: вот вот. Более того, мы даже не знаем, как все это добро собирается (хотя думаю, это студия).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, дело именно в двойном определении `powmod`.

Если заведомо известно, что в обоих случаях нужна именно одна и та же функция (как в данный момент)

1. Если функция внешняя, т.е. возможно нужна и другим модулям проекта, то одну убрать, другую оставить.
2. Если функция чисто внутренняя для модуля, то, возможно, ради сохранения независимости модулей стоит сохранить обе копии, но объявить их  `static` (или заключить в безымянный namespace). Сделать то же самое и с другими внутренними по своей сути функциями.

Если же эти функции совпали чисто случайно, то переименовать их, чтобы устранить совпадение имен.